# How to extract date from the source file name

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

to_timestamp_ntz(substring(SOURCE_OF_RECORD,REGEXP_INSTR(SOURCE_OF_RECORD, '.json')-14,14),'yyyymmddhh24miss') AS EXTRACTED_AT

file name :-OEA_CustomerOnboarded_Czech_20230208085230.JSON

Comment: Writing a title and dumping some code is not going to work out well for you here. You should clearly describe the problem you're having before including the code, and ask a **specific question** related to that code in the post body. I'd suggest you review [ask] and then [edit] your post - if you don't, it will most likely be closed.

Answer (score 0):

breaking this down:

```
select
    column1 as SOURCE_OF_RECORD
    ,REGEXP_INSTR(SOURCE_OF_RECORD, '.json') as a
    ,a - 14 as b
    ,substring(SOURCE_OF_RECORD, b, 14) as c
    ,to_timestamp_ntz(c, 'yyyymmddhh24miss') as d
    --to_timestamp_ntz(substring(SOURCE_OF_RECORD,REGEXP_INSTR(SOURCE_OF_RECORD, '.json')-14,14),'yyyymmddhh24miss') AS EXTRACTED_AT    

from values
    ('OEA_CustomerOnboarded_Czech_20230208085230.JSON')
```

gives the error:

> Can't parse '208085230.JSON' as timestamp with format 'yyyymmddhh24miss'

so flipping to try_ version, I get null for d

but can see that my date extract is not working as intended.

Firstly REGEXP_INSTR is case sensitive, via the `'i'` option.

```
select
    column1 as SOURCE_OF_RECORD
    ,REGEXP_INSTR(SOURCE_OF_RECORD, '.json', 1, 1, 0, 'i') as a
    ,a - 14 as b
    ,substring(SOURCE_OF_RECORD, b, 14) as c
    ,try_to_timestamp_ntz(c, 'yyyymmddhh24miss') as d
from values
    ('OEA_CustomerOnboarded_Czech_20230208085230.JSON'),
    ('OEA_CustomerOnboarded_Czech_20230208085230.json')
;
```

now this gives:

| SOURCE_OF_RECORD | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| OEA_CustomerOnboarded_Czech_20230208085230.JSON | 43 | 29 | 20230208085230 | 2023-02-08 08:52:30.000 |
| OEA_CustomerOnboarded_Czech_20230208085230.json | 43 | 29 | 20230208085230 | 2023-02-08 08:52:30.000 |

if you always expect `.json` you could just use:

```
left(right(SOURCE_OF_RECORD, 19), 14)
```

thus:

```
try_to_timestamp_ntz(left(right(SOURCE_OF_RECORD, 19), 14), 'yyyymmddhh24miss')
```

Answer (score 0):

The other option is to divide and conquer using `split_part()`

```
 select try_to_timestamp_ntz(split_part(split_part(col,'_',-1),'.',1), 'yyyymmddhh24miss')
```